# WCF Service Http Persistent Connection/Session

Tags: c#, wcf

I am aware that HTTP 1.1 can close a connection using the "Connection: close" header in basic socket programming. 
Is it possible to create a persistent http connection or session using WCF service? For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestServiceInstance
{
    class ServiceTest  :IServiceTest
    {
        private int i = 0;
        public ServiceTest()
        {
            ++i;
        }
        public int PrintNumber()
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ServiceTestImplementation.ServiceRef;

namespace ServiceTestImplementation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServiceTestClient client = new ServiceTestClient();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(client.PrintNumber());
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

It always print 1 - but I would like it if the service instance can remember its value...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WCF allows you to persist sessions between client calls.

You can use WCF sessions to accomplish this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand most of the instructions.
Apparently SessionMode = SessionMode.Required isn't enough

Comment: I think it works thanks - I only incremented the value it in the constructor. Perhaps it was working all along.